# My recent answer missing from activity

Tags: support, answers, deleted-answers

I answered an asp.net question on stackoverflow few minutes back, but its not showing up in my activitis. I do understand the question might have been deleted, but is there a way to track that. I did not receive any reputation for that answer (although I was expecting so :p), so it not showing as any reputation change also.

Comment: I got the same problem, once the question is deleted your point from answering are away. Unfortunately, you can only see that in your history the question has been deleted

Comment: I am not sure but have you checked [your deleted recent answers](http://stackoverflow.com/users/recently-deleted-answers/1549209)?

Comment: Thank's for the answers guys. hims056 I didn't know about that. I just check it and my answer is showing there. If you could post this as answer I would accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see your recently deleted answers or questions which are less than 60 days old from your profile. Go to your answers or questions tab where you can see a link like *deleted recent answers* or *deleted recent question* at the bottom.